# How to fill out a web form and return the data with knowing the web form id/name in python

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am currently trying to automatically submit information into the web forms on this website : https://coinomi.com/recovery-phrase-tool.html Unfortunately I do not know the name of the forms, and cant seem to find out from its source code. Now I have tried to fill out the forms using the requests python module, and just by passing the parameters through the URL before scraping it. Unfortunately I have trouble finding the name of the form so I cant do this.

If possible I wanted to do this with the offline version of the website at https://github.com/Coinomi/bip39/blob/master/bip39-standalone.html so that it is more secure but I barely know how to use regular web forms with the tools I have, let alone locally from my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly are you looking for. However, here is a part of code, which use `selenium` to fill some parts of the form that you mention.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

browser = browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users...\\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://coinomi.com/recovery-phrase-tool.html')

# Example to fill a text box 
recoveryPhrase = browser.find_element_by_id('phrase')
recoveryPhrase.send_keys('your answer')

# Example to select a element 
numberOfWords = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('strength'))
numberOfWords.select_by_visible_text('24')


# Example to click a button
generateRandomMnemonic = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/div/div/span/button')
generateRandomMnemonic.click()
```